# Рассортировать Map по наименьшему значению

Tags: java

Например, у меня есть код:

```
Map<String, Double> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("five", 5D);
map1.put("six", 6D);
map1.put("one", 1D);
map1.put("two", 2D);
map1.put("zero", 0D);
```

мне надо рассортировать всё, что есть в списке, чтобы вывело:

```
zero - 0
one - 1
two - 2 
five - 5
six - 6
```

Помогите, пожалуйста =)

Comment: off - строчная `d` более читабельна, ИМХО

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) не гарантирует сохранения упорядоченности элементов.
[image: сортировка неупорядоченной коллекции]

Используйте [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) или [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: Спасибо, я рассортировал LinkedHashMap, но мне нужно теперь карту "перевернуть", у меня получается
    six - 6
    five - 5
    two - 2
    one - 1
    zero - 0,

а мне надо наоборот

Comment: `map1.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())).forEach(System.out::println)`

Answer (score 1):

Можно отсортировать, используя Collection.sort. Но перед этим map надо сделать списком:

```
Map<String, Double> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("five", 5D);
map1.put("six", 6D);
map1.put("one", 1D);
map1.put("two", 2D);
map1.put("zero", 0D);

List<Map.Entry<String, Double>> list = new LinkedList<>(map1.entrySet());
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Double>>() {
 public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Double> o1, Map.Entry<String, Double> o2) {
  return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
 }
});

for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : list) {
 System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если очень хочется использовать `java.util.HashMap`, то можно сделать так:

```
map
   .entrySet()
   .stream()
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue, Comparator.naturalOrder()))
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Можно проще, без явного компаратора - `.stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())`.

Comment: что то не могу придумать как это можно было бы сделать в hashmap

Comment: `map1.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).forEach(System.out::println)`