# Проблема сортировки

Tags: java, сортировка

Имеется код:

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class C {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    ValueComparator bvc = new ValueComparator(map);
    TreeMap<String, Integer> sorted_map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(bvc);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FruitSort fruitSort = new C().new FruitSort();
        fruitSort.enterChat();
    }

    class FruitSort {
        private String[] massivFruit;

        void enterChat() {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int number = scanner.nextInt();
            massivFruit = new String[number];

            for (int i = 0; i < massivFruit.length; i++) {
                Scanner scannerName = new Scanner(System.in);
                String name = scannerName.next();
                massivFruit[i] = name;
            }
            sortFruit();
        }

        void sortFruit() {
            for (int i = 0; i < massivFruit.length; i++) {
                int count = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < massivFruit.length; j++) {
                    if (massivFruit[i].equals(massivFruit[j])) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                map.put(massivFruit[i], count);
            }


            sorted_map.putAll(map);
            System.out.println(sorted_map);
            for (String key : sorted_map.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(key);
            }
        }
    }
    class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {
        Map<String, Integer> base;

        public ValueComparator(Map<String, Integer> base) {
            this.base = base;
        }
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вроде все работает но одно .Если делаю тестирование к примеру ввожу:

```
6
Яблоко
Лимон
Дыня
Дыня
Лимон
Яблоко
```

То происходит вывод:

```
{Лимон=2, Яблоко=2, Дыня=2}
Лимон
Яблоко
Дыня
```

Вопрос у меня следующий. Мне нужен следующий порядок:

`Яблоко = 2 , Лимон = 2, Дыня = 2`

А почему то меняются местами элементы . Возможно сделать что бы их порядок был таков, если значения `values` совпадают то порядок остался таким же как и был введен. Если к примеру `values` больше чем остальные то печатается вверху. 
К примеру:

```
5
Лимон
Яблоко
Яблоко
Банан
Киви
```

Должно вывести:

```
Яблоко = 2, Банан = 1,Киви = 1,Лимон = 1
```

Comment: В данном случае нужен компаратор, который в качестве вторичного ключа учитывает порядковый номер предмета, под которым он в первый раз появился.

Comment: это мап, что ты от него хотел

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Рассортировать Map по наименьшему значению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/720822/204271)